# Angular Directives watching external models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In learning Angular I am creating a simple gallery that can be zoomed.  My initial implementation used a simple ng-repeat, but I quickly discovered that based on the zoom of the gallery I would want to change things like the url source (from small to medium thumbs), and probably the css on captions etc.

```
<div class="photoHolder" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter:{caption:query} | orderBy:orderProp" ng-attr-style="transition: .3s ease; width: {{thumbWidth}}px; height: {{thumbWidth}}px;">
    <div class="photoClass" data-id="{{photo.id}}" ng-attr-style="background-image:url({{zoomSize < 5 ? photo.thumb_url : photo.medium_url}})"></div>
    <div class="caption">{{photo.caption}}</div>
    <div class="caption">{{photo.date}}</div>
</div>
```

So, I switched to a much cleaner directive:

```
<gal-photo class="photoHolder" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter:{caption:query} | orderBy:orderProp"/>
```

but the only way I could get the directive element to respond to the zoom change is to add a watch to the zoom inside the link for the element:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var image = new Image();
    scope.photo.url = scope.zoomSize < 5 ? scope.photo.thumb_url : scope.photo.medium_url;
    scope.$watch('thumbWidth', function() {
           scope.photo.url = scope.zoomSize < 5 ? scope.photo.thumb_url : scope.photo.medium_url;
        element.attr('style',  'transition: .3s; width: ' + scope.thumbWidth + 'px; height: ' + scope.thumbWidth + 'px;');
    });
}
```

I know that you aren't supposed to abuse watches, and my fear is that with 500 elements in the gallery you are doing 500 watches.  But I can find no guidance on responding to external inputs within repeating directives. The two galleries seem to perform about the same, but I am wondering if I am doing this wrong?  Here is a fiddle for the [original gallery](http://jsfiddle.net/ksoncan34/j3wGa/2/) and a fiddle for the [directive version](http://jsfiddle.net/ksoncan34/hRaH9/3/).

Comment: I liked your original solution with ng-attr-style, because it's less code, but it sounds like this is more of a performance question. I would check out questions like this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702140/improving-nested-ng-repeat-directive-performance

Comment: Yeah, I already checked that out...  I'm looking for guidance in the way that people handle external inputs within models.  Like I said the performance isn't noticeably different.  I prefer the directive as it is less HTML and seems more powerful, I was just wondering if I was doing it wrong.

Comment: This is a really good one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Beyers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21867803/2544296) is right that watches are actually pretty efficient.

Still, here's how you could do this with a **single** watch by using a parent directive for the whole image gallery:

```
myApp.directive('imageGallery', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        function updatePhotos() {
            $element.children().attr('style',  'transition: .3s; width: ' + $scope.thumbWidth + 'px; height: ' + $scope.thumbWidth + 'px;');
            $scope.photos.forEach(function(photo){
                photo.url = $scope.zoomSize < 5 ? photo.thumb_url : photo.medium_url;
            });
        };

        this.updatePhotos = updatePhotos;
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch('thumbWidth', function() {   
            ctrl.updatePhotos();
        });
        ctrl.updatePhotos();
    }
}
});
```

[(full fiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/abeluga/3fEn5/1/)

Notice that I've put the central updating logic into the `controller` rather than the `link` function.  That's not strictly necessary here, but it could be useful in the future, because that controller object would be visible to the child `galPhoto` directives.  (See the two "NOTE" comments in the fiddle.)

Comment: Holy cow that is smooth compared to the other versions.  (Beyers and my original).

Comment: Heh, thanks.  It's worth noting, though, that since each instance of the galPhoto directive references its 'photo' object via the {{}} interpolation, the number of watches in this solution is still basically proportional to the number of photos... they're just under the hood instead of in your code.

Answer (score 6):

Your use case is a good candidate for $scope events. Have one watch inside your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('thumbWidth', function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('thumbWidthChange');
});
```

And then in your directive register listeners for this event:

```
scope.$on('thumbWidthChange', function(){
    scope.photo.url = scope.zoomSize < 5 ? scope.photo.thumb_url : scope.photo.medium_url;
    element.attr('style',  'transition: .3s; width: ' + scope.thumbWidth + 'px; height: ' + scope.thumbWidth + 'px;');
});
```

Scope event listeners are only called when their events are fired, so this should limit the watch list and optimize performance.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv7fy/1/) based on your example using the events method: http://jsfiddle.net/dv7fy/1/

As a side note, performance of Angular watches scales better than what most think, have a look at this example (still on Angular 1.0.3, should be even better on latest version): http://jsfiddle.net/mhevery/cXMPJ/11/