# Does adding directives increase ng-repeat performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

Angular JS  version : 1.2.26

In an effort to decrease render time I moved my image and title binding into a couple custom directives. I've done a bit of reading and most seem to point to using directive or a hybrid of directives and binding to increase render performance.

Lazyloading is already implemnted , I will be looking into using bind once as well .

Any thoughts on how I could increase the performance of ng-repeat as the list of n items becomes larger ?

Original code:

```
<div ng-repeat='mediaitem in mediaitems track by $index' on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
    <button data-ng-click="onItemClicked(mediaitem)" id="{{$index}}" save-scroll > 
        <img img-preload  width="100%" ng-src='{{mediaitem.img0 || mediaitem.img1 }}' />
        <div align="center" class="title" ng-bind="mediaitem.titlefull" > </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Revised code:

```
<div ng-repeat='mediaitem in mediaitems track by $index' on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
   <button  data-ng-click="onItemClicked(mediaitem)" id="{{$index}}" save-scroll > 
      <img  img-preload  width="100%" set-image />
      <div align="center" class="title" set-title> </div> 
  </button>
</div>
```

Directives: 
.....

```
  .directive('setTitle',function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link : function(scope,element,attrs){
                element.html(scope.mediaitem.titlefull);
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('setImage',function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link : function(scope,element,attrs){
                var imgsrc = scope.mediaitem.img1;
                if(!imgsrc){
                    imgsrc = scope.mediaitem.img2;
                }

                try{
                    element.attr('src',imgsrc);
                }
                catch(err){
                }
            }
        };
    })
```

Comment: What are your performance stats comparing the two methods? I would think you'll get your best performance boost using bind once. Also Angular has made some performance improvements since 1.2.x, so it would be nice to see what stats you see.

Comment: @Beyers, right now I'm testing on the amazon firetv with a relatively small list off 200 items w/ images .  ng-repeat and render times average around 2200/ms with just angular bindings and 2000/ms from start to finish with the directives swapped in for the bindings. I suspect the two values will probably diverge as the list gets bigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improving nested ng-repeat + directive performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702140/improving-nested-ng-repeat-directive-performance)