# Nested ng-repeat performance issue in IE

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Am using nested `ng-repeat` to display below JSON ( given sample format actual format is different and have lot of properties ). When list size is 100 then in IE it takes more than 25 seconds to render.

I tried using "track by" & "oen way binding" but no luck.

### Data

```
{name: "name1", placeVisited: [{city: 'city1', state: "state1"}]}
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.name" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="float: none; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer"  >
    <a class="tile" id="tile{{$index}}"  >
        <div class="tile-head">
            <div class="tile-ont-img"><img src="user.png" class="img-responsive" > </div>


            <h4>{{::item.name}}</h4>


        </div>
        <div class="tile-body" >
            <p ng-repeat="place in ::item.placeVisited track by port.state" >
                State {{::place.state}}                   
            </p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Please share your idea to improve nested ng-repeat performance in IE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702140/improving-nested-ng-repeat-directive-performance

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I am using ng-if in all the places, using pagination page size is 100. for 100 records it takes 30 seconds.

Comment: Your performance problems may be due to the `ng-if` directives. They add new scopes and watchers.